# The links sometimes don't work correctly on iOS

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I realised that sometimes the links in emails don't work correctly on the iOS. The links redirect to the App Store instead of the mobile app.

Is there a workaround for that in Marketing Cloud?

The thing which switch the settings and makes the links not working is 'open in a web browser' button in the email.

Comment: It might be linked to deep linking. Check out this article  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_ios_universal_link.htm&type=5

Comment: My guess is this is related to your particular settings in your iOS device. Have you tested this by sending to a different iOS device (and account). In other words, how the device decides to handle certain links (https:// or mailto://) are not controlled by Marketing Cloud. Alternately, if you provide more specifics about which types of links are causing the App Store to open or not, that might give more information to figure out if it's a way you're coding links in the email.